# State in react component won't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My react component won't load the data from the state, at all.
My loading function works as expected, as well as the rendering for it, however, even though the state updates (I logged it, it does return the expected data) nothing with render related to it.
If posts are empty, the `<p>nothing</>` tag does not show, and if there is data, it's not printed in the p tag nor is it loaded into my carousel.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withFirebase } from '../Firebase';
import AliceCarousel from 'react-alice-carousel';
import 'react-alice-carousel/lib/alice-carousel.css';

import PostItem from '../Market/PostItem';

class LandingPosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      text: '',
      loading: false,
      posts: [],
      limit: 5,
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.onListenForMessages();
  }

  onListenForMessages = () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    this.props.firebase
      .collectionGroup('settings')
      .where('homepagepost', '==', true)
      .get().then(snapshot => {

      let posts = [];

      snapshot.forEach(doc => {

        doc.ref.parent.parent.get().then(doc => {
          posts.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id });
          console.log(posts);
        });

      });

      this.setState({ posts: posts.reverse(), loading: false });

    });
  };


  responsive = {
    0: { items: 1 },
    1024: { items: 3 },
  };

  render() {
    const { loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {loading && <div>Loading ...</div>}
        {this.state.posts && (
          <p>{this.state.posts[0]}</p>
        )}
        {!this.state.posts && (
          <p>nothing</p>
        )}
        <AliceCarousel
          items={this.state.posts.map(item => {return <PostItem data={item}/>})}
          responsive={this.responsive}
          autoPlayInterval={2000}
          autoPlayDirection="rtl"
          autoPlay={true}
          fadeOutAnimation={true}
          mouseDragEnabled={true}
          disableAutoPlayOnAction={true}
          buttonsDisabled={true}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withFirebase(LandingPosts);
```

Comment: What does the updated state object look like for posts?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo, when logging the state, I get this `[{…}]
0:
category: "Cats"
createdAt: Timestamp {seconds: 1571026757, nanoseconds: 501000000}
desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame..."
picture: "this was a photo link"
price: 1000
title: "Cute Puppy"
uid: "I06U2O54p8Aqa5GxS5MU"
userId: "tvgfDZ1aaJalEzI0nDkHMdYQxa03"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)`

Comment: The expression `this.state.posts` will always be truthy - _i.e._ `Boolean([])` - you should be checking `posts.length`.  Your posts are also objects, when you pass `{this.state.posts[0]}` to React it's going to treat it as an expanded JSX element, not mapping to anything it knows how to render. Either you need to translate the post into appropriate markup or if you just want to debug the data, convert it to a readable string: `{JSON.stringify(this.state.posts[0])}`.

Comment: @Emissary I've checked using .length, and also stringified for debugging, however, now those two debug elements are always active, and the stringified debug returns 0. My carousel still does not render though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, following code is async in in your case.

```
doc.ref.parent.parent.get().then(doc => {
    posts.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id });
    console.log(posts);
});
```

If so try adding setting state in then or create array of promise like this.

```
posts.push(
 doc.ref.parent.parent.get().then(doc => {
    posts.push({ ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id });
    console.log(posts);
 });
)
Promise.all(posts).then((_posts)=>this.setState({ posts: _posts.reverse(), loading: false });)
```

Comment: After fiddling with this a little, it worked! Thanks a lot! For anyone else reading, I created another array called postItems, pushed my doc data into that, and in the Promise func, set my posts state to postItems.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to "repeat" your state declaration inside render.
Like this:

> const {
>         text,
>         loading,
>         posts,
>         limit
>       } = this.state

At least that's how I have it in my components

Comment: This is the way it originally was, yet it still didn't work. I just tried it again but it still won't render.